# Make a div background white

Tags: html, joomla3.0

This may see quite simple, but I'm trying to make a div background white and I can't!

You can see a developing site right here:

http://www.issencial.com/2015/

I have a video background, a div with nav (rt-header) and then a div (rt-feature) that I wanna white so when people scroll down, it overlaps the video one.

I guess it is all set, but only content is white, not the whole div...

Can anyone help me on this?

Many thanks in advance...

Comment: Add `position: relative;` to the div (`#rt-feature`).

Comment: as per @ɴᴀᴛʜ suggestion setting position to relative will fix it

Comment: Yes, that's correct! position: relative solve's it...

Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that should be it:

```
#rt-feature {
background: none no-repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does...

```
background-color:white;
```

on "rt-grid-12 rt-alpha rt-omega"  achieve the effect you're going for?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specify position to absolute so by default it was taking position
:static . The element is positioned relative to its first positioned.And instead of using background only use background-color since its for div.Try with following code

```
 #rt-feature {
 background-color: #ffffff;
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
}

  #rt-header {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #000000;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
  }
```

Comment: Please explain the code instead of posting only the code.

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS Property

```
#rt-feature { position: relative;}
```